# Webkit desktop notification - has no method 'createHTMLNotification'

Tags: methods, webkit, notifications, desktop

The webkit html notification (createHTMLNotification) work fine until yesterday. An error is appear (see below), the code has not change -> incompatible with the last version of chrome ?

```
Error message : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NotificationCenter> has no method 'createHTMLNotification'
```

If I use the methode "createNotification", it's work fine but I need to use HTML notification.

The settings of chrome allowed the pop-up and notification for all website (and tests are in the code for check that).

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunate, this feature has removed from chromium ...

see : https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/8vWo8hq4pDm

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications.html

Warning: webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification() in the web notifications API has been deprecated. The new web notifications API only allows text. Chrome notifications API will be promoted to stable soon and web notifications will be updated to use the new rich notifications format.

there is still hope.